# NoMethodError in Transactions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a new transaction on my Rails database banking application, but when I click new, I get this error:

> NoMethodError in Transactions#new
>   Showing app/views/transactions/_transaction_form.html.erb where line #10 raised:
>   undefined method `dateD' for #

Around line 10, which is:

```
9:     <%= f.label :dateD %><br />
10:     <%= f.date_select :dateD %>
```

It seems to error even if I delete this, but with different errors. Here's my `_transaction_form.html.erb`, I use this on my edit/new pages, and edit seems to work fine, but as soon as I go to new, I get the errors posted above. Here's the code for the new:

#### _transaction_form.html.erb

```
<% form_for(@bank_account,@transaction) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :bank_account_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :bank_account_id %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :dateD %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :dateD %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :trans_type %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :trans_type %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :amount %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :amount %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :new_balance %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :new_balance %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :transaction_success %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :transaction_success %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

#### TransactionsController#new

```
def new
    @transaction = @bank_account.transactions.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @transaction }
    end
end
```

Comment: Please show us your Transaction schema, it just looks like `dateD` isn't an attribute of a Transaction

Comment: I pulled this out of the database migration I used when I created the scaffold: 

def self.up
    create_table :transactions do |t|
      t.date :dateD
      t.string :type
      t.decimal :amount
      t.decimal :new_balance
      t.boolean :transaction_success
      t.timestamps
    end
end

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I figured it out. It seemed that I missed [] from here:
<% form_for([@bank_account,@transaction]) do |f| %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things. Your `form_for` should use `<%=` and not `<%` and should have `[]` around the `@bank, @transaction` parts:

```
<%= form_for([@bank_account,@transaction]) do |f| %>
```